# Change UITableViewCell background color in Interface builder

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to avoid adding any code to my iOS project that has to do with visual set up since that's what Interface Builder is supposed to streamline for you.

So I'm trying to set up the prototype cell in IB and then just call:

```
TableCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];
```

The problem is if I change the background color for the cell in IB it remains white when I run my application. I can preset the color of the label fine but not the background color attribute in the Table Cell.

As an additional note, I can see that the UIView that is the backgroundView inside the cell is null after breakpointing and inspecting the variable after it's been initialized.

**UPDATE**
I'm getting the impression that the option for background color in IB is essentially useless? I'd rather not believe that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that unfortunately.

Change the background colour of the cell in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

From the documentation of `UITableViewCell`:

> Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property declared by UIView) you must do it in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the delegate and not in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the data source. Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded rectangle instead of the area outside of it.

Comment: Why is the option available in IB if it's essentially useless?

Comment: That is what I have been asking myself too...check the edited answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder, add a view as a subview of the cell, that will be your background view.  You can then add all labels or anything else as subviews to that view.  Change that views background color as you want.

Comment: But a table cell already has a subview that's meant to be it's background. I can't imagine this work around is the best option.

Comment: Would you know any reason why IB would not let me add a uiview as a subview to a tablecell?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a bug in IB. You can add views to that bar at the bottom of the controller, and then connect those views to the backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView properties of the cell. However, the backgroundView's color doesn't work, while the selectedBackgroundView's color does work correctly. If you add a background view in code to a custom table view cell and give it a backgroundColor, that does work.